# nexus bower registry download to a wrong place

Tags: bower, nexus

I have setup a nexus proxy registry for bower. I am using Debian 9.
bower version is 1.8.8, installed bower-nexus3-resolver (version 1.0.4).
My .bowerrc is like this:

```
{
  "directory": "components",
  "registry" :
  {
    "search" : [ "http://myserver.com:8081/repository/my_bower_pub/" ]
  },
  "resolvers" : [ "bower-nexus3-resolver" ]
}
```

under `~/temp/bower_tst` directory, I do `bower install q`. Then I see `~/temp/bower_tst/q-2.0.2`, which has all the package files. However, under `~/temp/bower_tst/components/q` the directory is empty.
I switched to use https://registry.bower.io and removed bower-nexus3-resolver, the .bowerrc is like:

```
{
  "directory": "components",
  "registry" :
  {
    "search" : [ "https://registry.bower.io" ]
  }
}
```

Then bower successfully downloaded `q` and installed it under the components directory. Please help, is this a bug of the bower-nexus3-resolver?

Comment: I am using Sonatype Nexus Repository ManagerOSS 3.22.0-02, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

It's because buggy bower-nexus3-resolver@1.0.4. After switching to version 1.0.2, it works just fine.

Comment: use your solution, it worked. Thanks!!